# minikube on virtual box loses HostOnly network after host was in sleep mode - How to recover?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

I'm running minikube with the vbox driver. I noticed that when I get back to my workstation after it's been in sleep mode, I can't do `kubectl get pods` (or any other `kubectl` command).

Some digging and I found that the the HostOnly network adapter of the minikube machine is not working. I logged in to the machine with `minikube ssh` and tried to restart the interface but I'm just getting an error.

```
$ ifdown eth1 
ifdown: can't open '/etc/network/interfaces': No such file or directory
```

the only thing currently working is to `minikube stop` and `minikube start` again. But that takes long and I just want to get back to work.

any ideas on how to fix the network quicker after it's been in sleep mode? or prevent it losing the network altogether?

Comment: Do you get any errors while trying to execute `kubectl` after being in sleep mode?

Comment: No. It justs hangs (that is what I expect after finding out that the VM's network interface is down)

Comment: Could you please check if you can see the HostOnly network in Preferences -> Network of your VirtualBox after you resume your work?

Comment: Yes I can. In the vbox settings. I also went thete to tick off and on the "cable connected" tickbox

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1):

`minikube start` should resume the cluster after being stopped/paused.

However, there is an issue with Minikube on VirtualBox and HostOnly network adapter that sometimes causes the adapter to stop working. When that happens you can do two things:

- Execute `minikube stop` and `minikube start` as you already tried which is a common workaround solution for this.
- Uninstall the VirtualBox and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is supposed to fix this issue.

This bug is being discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2439) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3614) if you'd like to know more details.